# How to update a list in Entity framework model?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

My scenario is as below:

I have a central database. I have an application based on the EF model. I have installed this application in several machines.

What I need to do is that when ever I update something in one machine, it should be reflected in the datagrid bound to an observable collection which is open in another machine.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you use?

Comment: I use SQL Server is not clear answer. Sql Server bla-bla-bla is preferred.

Comment: "How to update a list in Entity framework model" is far from describing your problem. It's more to "How notify clients from changes in the server data" or something like that. Each client commits changes to the server database? How is the communication implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class.

In the page there is an example showing how to implement it.

If your applications are not running as Administrator you will need to register the URL that you are listening to with Netsh